# Seemingly wrong CSS is being given priority

Tags: css

I'm having an issue where my CSS for td tag seems to be given priorty over more specific CSS class I've included, blue_link. The blue_link class appears at the bottom of the style sheet and I've confirmed the priority issue in Chrome's element inspector.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

CSS that is being given priority:

```
td a:link, td a:visited {
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Desired class:

```
a.blue_link  {
color: #5299c3; !important
text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td><a class="blue_link" href="profile/edit/<?php echo $profile_item['profile_id'] ?>">edit</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.blue_link, a.blue_link:link, a.blue_link:visited  {
    color: #5299c3;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @james I had tried a:link earlier, but knew it didn't make sense. So simple.

Answer (score 0):

Your important flag is in the wrong position:

```
a.blue_link  {
color: #5299c3 !important; 
text-decoration: none;
}
```

You should probably also apply the same pseudo classes for consistency and to get rid of the "!important".